# Ramda recommendation for removing duplicates from a slightly nested array

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

We're trying to utilise Ramda to avoid some brute-force programming. We have an array of objects that can look like this:

```
[
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1001]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1002]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000, 1003]},
{id: "002", failedReason: [1000]}
]
```

and we'd like to transform it so that it looks like this:

```
[
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003]},
{id: "002", failedReason: [1000]}
]
```

Essentially it reduces the array based on the id, and accumulates a sub-"failedReason" array containing all of the "failedReasons" for that id. We were hoping some Ramda magic might do this but so far we haven't found a nice means.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't easily test it on my phone, but something like this should work:

```
pipe(
  groupBy(prop('id')), 
  map(pluck('failedReason')),
  map(flatten),
  map(uniq)
)
```

**Update**

I just got around to looking at this on a computer, and noted that the output wasn't quite what you were looking for.  Adding two more steps would fix it:

```
pipe(
  groupBy(prop('id')), 
  map(pluck('failedReason')),
  map(flatten),
  map(uniq),
  toPairs,
  map(zipObj(['id', 'failedReason']))
)
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%20%22001%22%2C%20failedReason%3A%20%5B1000%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%20%22001%22%2C%20failedReason%3A%20%5B1001%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%20%22001%22%2C%20failedReason%3A%20%5B1002%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%20%22001%22%2C%20failedReason%3A%20%5B1000%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%20%22001%22%2C%20failedReason%3A%20%5B1000%2C%201003%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%20%22002%22%2C%20failedReason%3A%20%5B1000%5D%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Apipe%28%0A%20%20groupBy%28prop%28%27id%27%29%29%2C%20%0A%20%20map%28pluck%28%27failedReason%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28flatten%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28uniq%29%2C%0A%20%20toPairs%2C%0A%20%20map%28zipObj%28%5B%27id%27%2C%20%27failedReason%27%5D%29%29%0A%29%28data%29)**.

Comment: Scott - your answer was perfect. It has exactly the clean elegance we were trying (unsuccessfully) to achieve. Thank you for this - you are a Ramda Guru.

Special thanks to everyone else who contributed answers to this question. I am grateful for everyone's time.

Comment: Thanks.  You might also look more carefully at the very different answer from David Chambers.  His Thingy wrapper is probably worth doing only if it would help in other ways as well, but if it would, it would probably be better than this one-off solution.  (BTW, he and I are two of the primary authors of Ramda.)

Answer (score 2):

You could define a wrapper type which satisfies the requirements of [Monoid](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land/tree/v0.3.0#monoid). You could then simply use `R.concat` to combine values of the type:

```
//  Thing :: { id :: String, failedReason :: Array String } -> Thing
function Thing(record) {
  if (!(this instanceof Thing)) return new Thing(record);
  this.value = {id: record.id, failedReason: R.uniq(record.failedReason)};
}

//  Thing.id :: Thing -> String
Thing.id = function(thing) {
  return thing.value.id;
};

//  Thing.failedReason :: Thing -> Array String
Thing.failedReason = function(thing) {
  return thing.value.failedReason;
};

//  Thing.empty :: () -> Thing
Thing.empty = function() {
  return Thing({id: '', failedReason: []});
};

//  Thing#concat :: Thing ~> Thing -> Thing
Thing.prototype.concat = function(other) {
  return Thing({
    id: Thing.id(this) || Thing.id(other),
    failedReason: R.concat(Thing.failedReason(this), Thing.failedReason(other))
  });
};

//  f :: Array { id :: String, failedReason :: Array String }
//    -> Array { id :: String, failedReason :: Array String }
var f =
R.pipe(R.map(Thing),
       R.groupBy(Thing.id),
       R.map(R.reduce(R.concat, Thing.empty())),
       R.map(R.prop('value')),
       R.values);

f([
  {id: '001', failedReason: [1000]},
  {id: '001', failedReason: [1001]},
  {id: '001', failedReason: [1002]},
  {id: '001', failedReason: [1000]},
  {id: '001', failedReason: [1000, 1003]},
  {id: '002', failedReason: [1000]}
]);
// => [{"id": "001", "failedReason": [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003]},
//     {"id": "002", "failedReason": [1000]}]
```

I'm sure you could give the type a better name than Thing. ;)

Answer (score 1):

For fun, and mainly to explore the advantages of Ramda, I tried to come up with a "one liner" to do the same data conversion in *plain ES6*... I now fully appreciate the simplicity of [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41991146/3297291) :D

I thought I'd share my result because it nicely illustrates what a clear API can do in terms of readability. The chain of piped `map`s, `flatten` and `uniq` is so much easier to grasp...

I'm using `Map` for grouping and `Set` for filtering duplicate `failedReason`.

```js
const data = [ {id: "001", failedReason: [1000]}, {id: "001", failedReason: [1001]},  {id: "001", failedReason: [1002]}, {id: "001", failedReason: [1000]}, {id: "001", failedReason: [1000, 1003]}, {id: "002", failedReason: [1000]} ];

const converted = Array.from(data
  .reduce((map, d) => map.set(
      d.id, (map.get(d.id) || []).concat(d.failedReason)
    ), new Map())
  .entries())
  .map(e => ({ id: e[0], failedReason: Array.from(new Set(e[1])) }));
  
console.log(converted);
```

If at east the `MapIterator` and `SetIterator`s would've had a `.map` or even a`.toArray` method the code would've been a bit cleaner.

Comment: OTOH, the only things that make this hard to read and to reason about are `(map.get(d.id) || [])` and `e[0]`/`e[1]`.  But yes, a nice `.map` or `.toArray` would clean this up a lot.  Nicely done!