# Keep all the keys of the object after removing duplicates from a slightly nested array

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have the same issue of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41990038/10028754) but my objects have more keys for example:

```
[{
  id: 1
  name: "abcd",
  value: 123,
  type: "foo"
},
{
  id: 1
  name: "abcd",
  value: 321,
  type: "faa"
},
{
  id: 2
  name: "dcba",
  value: 456,
  type: "baa"
}]
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "abcd",
  value: [123, 321],
  type: ["foo", "faa"]
},
{
  id: 2
  name: "dcba",
  value: [456],
  type: ["baa"]
}]
```

The extra keys have the same value.

Comment: I think your question title is inaccurate, it's not slightly nested it has duplicate keys so needs objects to be merged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to group by the `id`, then map each group of objects, pick the `id` and `name` from the 1st object, extract all `value` and `type` from all objects in the group, transpose, and zip to an another object, and merge them.

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, values, map, converge, merge, head, pick, props, transpose, zipObj } = R

const fn = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('id')), // groupBy the id
  values, // convert the object of groups to array of groups
  map(converge(merge, [ // map each group by merging the results of...
    pipe(head, pick(['id', 'name'])), // getting the id and name from the 1st item
    pipe(map(props(['value', 'type'])), transpose, zipObj(['value', 'type'])) // extract the value and type and zipping to an object
  ]))
)

const data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "abcd",
  value: 123,
  type: "foo"
},
{
  id: 1,
  name: "abcd",
  value: 321,
  type: "faa"
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "dcba",
  value: 456,
  type: "baa"
}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the distinct id , loop over them and group them using filter and map

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "abcd",
    value: 123,
    type: "foo"
},
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "abcd",
        value: 321,
        type: "faa"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "dcba",
        value: 456,
        type: "baa"
    }];

//grab unique
let distinct = [...new Set(data.map(a => a.id))];

let grouped = distinct.map(d => {
    let filtered=data.filter(d1 => d1.id === d);
    return {
        id: d,
        name: filtered.map(d2 => d2.name)[0],
        value: [...new Set(filtered.map(d2 => d2.value))],
        type: [...new Set(filtered.map(d2 => d2.type))]
    }
});
console.log(grouped);
```